# better way to build association in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, controller

I need a link in a show method of a parent class for creating associated models, so I have the code:

```
link_to "incomplete", new_polymorphic_path(part_c.underscore, :survey_id => survey.id)
```

in a helper.

This links to a part, which has new code like this:

```
# GET /source_control_parts/new
def new
  get_collections
  if params[:survey_id]
    @s = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
    if @s.blank?
      @source_control_part = SourceControlPart.new
    else
      @source_control_part = @s.create_source_control_part
    end
  else
    @source_control_part = SourceControlPart.new
  end
end
```

I know this is not very DRY.  How can I simplify this?  Is there a RAILS way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
def new
  get_collections
  get_source_control_part
end

private
def get_source_control_part
  survey = params[:survey_id].blank? ? nil : Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
  @source_control_part = survey ? survey.create_source_control_part : SourceControlPart.new
end
```